# changing the background color of each other cell in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a uiTableView. I want that each other cell gets another background color. I am trying it like this. But it won't work. Anybody have a clue?

```
 if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
```

Kind regards,

Stef

Comment: The code looks good on first sight. What do you mean by "it won't work"? Does it crash? Are all cells white? And you might need to show more code, i.e. the full method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use : `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` instead of `cell.backgroundColor` inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Or : (from Apple docs)

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting
>   the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property
>   declared by UIView) you must do it in the
>   tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate
>   and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source.
>   Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view
>   has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of
>   the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded
>   rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

Comment: This works fine, but my labels backgrounds keeps getting white ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.backgroundView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
[cell.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

will do the job or

```
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Allocating a view each time for each cell can be ver costly if the table view has a lot of cells

Comment: this works, but my labels keeps getting a white background. Moxy what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the expanded question in the comments, set the background colour of your labels to `label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`